# Inflate Custom Layout ExpandableList Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I've been trying for two days to inflate my custom Layout for both groups and children in the expandable list using Fragment without success. I always get the error :
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams, but i do not know what it means!!

Here is my Fragment Class and the Adapter

```
public class ExpandableListFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.
 */
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
 */
public static ExpandableListFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    ExpandableListFragment fragment = new ExpandableListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ExpandableListFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalogo,
            container, false);
     ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista_catalogo);
     MiaExpandableListAdapter mela = new MiaExpandableListAdapter(getActivity());
        mela.loadJSONFromAsset();
        elv.setAdapter(mela);           
    return rootView;
}


public class MiaExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private String[] groups ={"sedie", "tavoli" , "divani" , "letti" , "lampade"};

    private String[][] children;

    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MiaExpandableListAdapter(Context ct)
    {
        ctx =ct;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = ExpandableListFragment.this.getActivity().getAssets().open("prova.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
            //Log.d("JSON", json);



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        children = new String[5][2];
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray nome_oggetto = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("sedie");
            for (int i=0; i<nome_oggetto.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject prodotto = nome_oggetto.getJSONObject(i);
                children[0][i] = prodotto.getString("name");
                //Log.d("JSONSEDIE", children[0][i]);

            }
            }catch(JSONException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray nome_oggetto = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("tavoli");
            for (int i=0; i<nome_oggetto.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject prodotto = nome_oggetto.getJSONObject(i);
                children[1][i] = prodotto.getString("name");

            }
            }catch(JSONException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray nome_oggetto = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("divani");
            for (int i=0; i<nome_oggetto.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject prodotto = nome_oggetto.getJSONObject(i);
                children[2][i] = prodotto.getString("name");

            }
            }catch(JSONException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray nome_oggetto = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("letti");
            for (int i=0; i<nome_oggetto.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject prodotto = nome_oggetto.getJSONObject(i);
                children[3][i] = prodotto.getString("name");

            }
            }catch(JSONException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray nome_oggetto = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("lampade");
            for (int i=0; i<nome_oggetto.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject prodotto = nome_oggetto.getJSONObject(i);
                children[4][i] = prodotto.getString("name");

            }
            }catch(JSONException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}



        return json;

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }       @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_catalogo);
        tv.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return tv;

    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_catalogo);
        tv.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

        return tv;
    }
   @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Here are the layouts i tried to inflate: child_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/child_catalogo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="17dp" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

and group_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/group_catalogo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="30dp" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally the Fragment layout fragment_catalogo.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.lab2mad.ExpandableListFragment" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lista_catalogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

if someone could give me some hints i would be very gratefully.
Thank you

Here you go the error Log:

> 05-05 21:51:15.718: W/dalvikvm(11944): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1816)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1785)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:705)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:762)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1633)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1422)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1243)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1049)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>   05-05 21:51:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11944):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks Again

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: keep trying...but no dice. I don't know where the problem is. can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this in onCreateView---

```
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalogo, container, false);
```

with this----

```
   LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(fragment_catalogo, container, false);
```